# Distinguish is-a and has-a relation in the LLVM IR code level

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

In the IR level of LLVM, is there any method exist to distinguish is-a and has-a relation between two classes relation?

If yes, how to check it using commands in the IR level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think llvm-IR will have this feature. It's a runtime type check, but LLVM-IR is static typed. So you should make you own runtime library, and you can add meta-data check in it.